# How do I automatically connect to a wireless network with auto-login?

Tags: 10.10, 10.04, wireless, network-manager, gnome-keyring

I want NetworkManager to automatically connect to the wireless network. I've configured my account to automatically log in (using `System > Administration > Login Window`) and I get prompted to unlock my GNOME keyring.

From researching this, it would appear that I should be able to disable the security on the keyring by blanking the password. However, if I change the password of the default keyring to blank so that it uses "Unsafe Storage" and automatically log in, I am prompted with a "Wireless Network Authentication Required" request. The password field is already filled in but does not seem to have been used.

So how do I convince NetworkManager and the GNOME Keyring to work without requiring me to log in with a password, or to enter my keyring password?

Comment: this is a duplicate of:
[this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/867/how-can-i-stop-being-prompted-to-unlock-the-default-keyring-on-boot) and
[this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/10683/why-does-network-manager-always-ask-for-my-keyring-password)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to do that:

1. Remove Password and Encryption Keys (`seahorse`), the program responsible for keyrings.
2. The alternative is to edit your wireless connection, and tick the last checkbox to make it available for all users. In this case, the network will be connected to before signing in, at the login (if there are multiple users or the only user account is password protected).

Of course, the second method is preferable if you still have uses from GNOME-Keyring.

Comment: I've changed the wireless connection to make it available for all users and it's been working for a few days now, so thanks Oxwivi!

Answer (score 2):

Solution 2) works fine but has an disadvantage:

only 1 Wifi network can be marked as "available for all users". If you want to connect to another Wifi, you will be prompter for password each time you connect.

I found following solution.

Config (for reference):

- Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid, localized to Slovak language
- Autologin
- Unsafe keyring (no password)

Procedure:

```
mpilka@mpilka:~/.gnome2/keyrings$ rm -f default
mpilka@mpilka:~/.gnome2/keyrings$ mv predvolený.keyring login.keyring
```

Both autologin and NetworkManager remembering passwords now works.

Edit: "predvolený" translates to "default" in English.